# SQLPLUS Table Query Trouble

Tags: sqlplus

I have a problem with one of my queries in SQLPLUS.

I have been asked to display the SuppCode, SuppName, and PostCode for all suppliers who satisfy the following contraints: Every stock item they supply has a price which is greater than the average of all stock items.

The three tables I'm working with are; Supppliers and Stocks and SupplyItems.

The Suppliers table looks looks like:

```
SUPPCODE SUPPNAME STREET TOWN COUNTRY POSTCODE TELNO FAXNO
```

With 8 seperate sample data (8 suppliers), and no null fields.

The Stocks table looks like:

```
ITEMNO STORECODE ITEMDESC QUANTITY UNITS REORDER PRICE SUPPCODE
```

With 40 seperate sample data (40 stock items), and no null fields.

The SupplyItems table looks like:

```
SUPPCODE CATNO STOCKNO PRICE
```

With 60 seperate sample data (60 supply items), and no null fields.

I have written the following query:

```
select distinct SU.SuppCode, Su.SuppName, PostCode
from Suppliers SU
LEFT JOIN SupplyItems SI ON SU.SuppCode = SI.SuppCode
where Price >
(select AVG(Quantity) from Stocks ST
where SI.StockNo = ST.StockNo);
```

I get the following output (4 values):

```
SUPPCODE SUPPNAME POSTCODE
S6       BSS LTD. B10 8SS
S2       ITX LTD. IT5 3TX
S3       FFG LTD. FY9 6FG
S4       OMM LTD. OM5 4MM
```

Now, I have been made aware that the output should contain either 2 or 3 records, so my query is wrong, though I can't see why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
where Price >
(select AVG(Quantity) from Stocks ST
```

looks wrong - shouldn't it rather be

```
AVG(price)
```

?

**EDIT:** also,

```
select distinct SU.SuppCode, Su.SuppName, PostCode
from Suppliers SU
LEFT JOIN SupplyItems SI ON SU.SuppCode = SI.SuppCode
where Price > ...
```

probably doesn't do what you want - this will return all suppliers who offer *at least one* item whose price is above the average; to get the suppliers that offer *only* items with price above the average, you'll have to use a different approach, e.g. (untested)

```
select distinct SU.SuppCode, Su.SuppName, PostCode
from Suppliers SU
where not exists (
  select null from SupplyItems si 
  where su.SuppCode = si.SuppCode
  and su.price <= (
      select AVG(price) from Stocks ST
      where SI.StockNo = ST.StockNo)
)
```

Comment: I've tried that previously. You mean, "where AVG(Price) > (select AVG(Quantity) from Stocks ST"? ... I got the error: "ORA-00934: Group function is not allowed here" when I tried

Comment: No. You're comparing the price with the average of the quantity - this doesn't make sense IMHO. You should compare the price of the supplied item with the average price instead of the average quantity.

Comment: Ah, how silly of me! Thanks, although I'm now getting 5 values instead of the 4, which by the sounds of it, isn't the correct answer. But I now see the comparing error

Comment: That's because your query returns all suppliers that offer at least one "expensive" item - see my updated answer.

Comment: hmm, I've found that I'm getting "No Records Selected". I have written a variant of the query you've suggested but nothing, shouldn't the "Price <=" actually be "Price >=" as per the "Every stock item they supply has a price which is greater than the average of all stock items." constraint?

Comment: No, since I'm using NOT EXISTS, it should be <= - I want to exclude all suppliers that have at least one "cheap" item in their portfolio. I'd suggest you post a complete example (table creation statements, inserts etc. - you can use sqlfiddle if you like) plus the output you're expecting from your query.

Comment: I understand, you have helped me out a lot, and thanks for the extended explanation in the comments here. I appreciate your help!